# lose stack trace when using Promise.then vs. async-await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await, promise

I have the following snippet implemented with `Promise.then`:

```js
function b() {
  return Promise.resolve()
}


function c() {
   throw new Error('error here')
}

const a = () => {
    b().then(() => c());
};


a()
```

The stack trace output from the error only included function `c`

```
VM57:6 Uncaught (in promise) Error: 343
    at c (<anonymous>:6:9)
    at <anonymous>:10:17
```

However, if I switch this to async-await as in:

```js
function b() {
  return Promise.resolve()
}


function c() {
   throw new Error('error here')
}

const a = async () => {
    await b()
    c()
};


a()
```

This time the stack trace included the whole call stack with function `a`

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: 343
    at c (<anonymous>:6:9)
    at a (<anonymous>:3:5)
```

I tested this in Chrome dev console. I wonder what caused the difference and does this mean one should stick with `async-await` for better debugbility? Also are there any resources I can learn more about this difference?

Comment: Its anonymous because its called inside an anonymous function: `() => c()`. In the other example its called inside `a`

Comment: https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async#improved-developer-experience

Answer (score 1):

This is expected.

In the `then` version, the function `a` has ran to completion before the `then` callback executes. That anonymous callback is the only function on the call stack at that moment. When `c` is called, and the rejection occurs, `a` is not on the call stack.

In the `await` version, the function `a` is first suspended (it returns a promise), but then when `b()` resolves, the execution context of `a` is restored and execution of `a` resumes. So when the rejection occurs in `c`, `a` is on the call stack.

Comment: got it! thanks for the explanation! Is there any scenario where `promise.then` is worse it terms of debugbility in comparison to `await`?

Comment: That is a matter of opinion. `then` callbacks are callbacks just like `setTimeout` has a callback argument: both execute when the call stack is empty. So I'd say there is no difference in terms of debugging. `async` `await` has the suspend/resume magic happening, which may give more context in debugging, but these mechanics form a higher level of abstraction, which may come with its own challenges of understanding what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Its anonymous because its called inside an anonymous function: `() => c()`. In the other example its called inside `a`

If you name your callback function, you will see the name inside the error log:

```
const a = () => {
  b().then(function test() {
    c();
  });
};
```

Comment: thanks. so `promise.then` and `await` are actually the same in terms of debuggability?